# PayPal Subscription work flow after creating the subscription buttons

Tags: paypal

I'm setting up the paypal REST Api's. I have the oAuth2 access token set up and I am in the process of setting up my products. My products are three types of subscriptions. Monthly, every 6 months and yearly.

I could also use some clarification on my work flow.

Basically, my products and my subscription plans are the same. My current flow:

1. Retrieve My access token from the oAuth2.
2. I create the product if one is not already created and stored in the db.
3. I create the subscription Plan if one is not already created and stored in the db.
4. I set up the subscription buttons using the javascript sdk.

I'm a bit lost after the button creation. Does PayPal finish everything else? Or Do I have to do the rest of what I listed below?

5. Activate the plan using the subscription Plan ID from either the db or the api call.
6. Create the subscription for the subscriber (this is done for every subscriber I presume)
7. Then I activate the subscription for the subscriber.
8. Capture Authorized Payment on Subscription **<-- Not sure what this is???**

Then I presume I use the webhooks that I set up in my PayPal account to get the subscription information to store on the server side for my subscriber???

I'm using PHP/MySQL as my back-end language for the server.

**EDIT**

The webhooks are showing up but I'm getting this in the transmission:

```
"transmissions": [
    {
      "webhook_url": "mySite.com/subscription/paypal-webhooks/index.php",
      "http_status": 404,
      "reason_phrase": "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established",
      "response_headers": {
        "Server": "Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1g",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "315",
        "Date": "Tue, 11 Jul 2023 16:34:35 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
      },
      "transmission_id": "b528bd70-2007-11ee-af26-6d2d8d30f0ad",
      "status": "PENDING",
      "timestamp": "2023-07-11T16:26:37Z"
    }
  ],
```

The http status is showing the 404. So apparently, it is not being able to locate my webhook file?? Do I need to URL encode the url since it has the dash for one of the file names?

When I use the webhook simulator. It is posting the time in my log.txt file.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);

    if (is_array($payload)) {
        $fh = fopen("log.txt", "a+");

        if ($fh) {
            fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fh);
        } else {
            trigger_error(error_log("Unable to open file!"));
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error(error_log("Invalid payload!"));
    }
}
```

I'm still missing something, but I am getting closer to having it work :)

Answer (score 0):

A normal subscription button uses `actions.subscription.create` to create the subscription. Optionally you can do so with the REST API and return the created ID within `createSubscription`, but this is not required.

However you create the subscription, alongside the `plan_id` you can add a `custom_id` value to help identify the user/profile it is associated with.

When a payer approves a subscription, it will immediately be active. There is no capture step.

To be notified reliably, do not rely on `onApprove` and whatever it may trigger, since that is a client-side callback and may not be invoked for whatever reason. Using the same app/client-id that creates the subscription, register for the webhook event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`. That is the only important webhook event name for subscriptions, all of your logic can be built around first receiving this and updating the good-through date for the subscription on your end (if a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED does not arrive in time, the subscription has lapsed)

Comment: Is there a way I can chat with you to get more details? I have tried to use my business account to create the subscription buttons for the user through the subscription dashboard. It works. But I do not have a way to capture those subscriptions. So I am trying to use the REST Api to set everything up. From my understanding, the webhooks do not work for the auto-generated buttons we get from the dashboard subsciption.

Comment: So I have my sandbox credentials. Under the default application is where I have the Api Credentials, the sandbox account info, the features (this is where I have subscriptions checked). Then I created a webhook for this default application. I chose all events just to try to figure out how it works. When I subscribe on my site, no webhook events show up in my webhook events. This is where I'm really getting lost.

Comment: Webhooks do work if you can find the corresponding client-id's app in https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications . The client-id must match the button's and plan_id's. There is no capture step for subscriptions, they are activated and start automatically once approved by a payer within PayPal.

Comment: @Presont PHX Found the problem why the webhook was not working... I believe. I will post the edit up in my question. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the webhook. Or the address is messed up.

Comment: Why am I retrieving data from the webhook simulator but when I subscribe with sandbox credentials, I do not get any data from my webhook endpoint? It does eventually propagate into the paypal error log though and it gives me the 404 status code as in the edit I did in my question.

Comment: I do not know why the endpoint would give a 404 to actual webhooks if the simulator is able to post to it, but the 404 is coming from that endpoint external to PayPal (presumably your server) and the issue needs to be resolved there.